# Changing the default button selection image on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this helpful piece of code from the MartinJHiggings website (thank you).

The code is designed to play streaming audio.  But it was designed when autoplay in browsers was allowed.  It is no longer.  But the default image is still 'pause' as it thinks audio is playing.

I basically want the default image to be 'play', which when clicked it should change to 'pause' and start the stream.
When clicked again, the image should change to 'play' and the stream should stop.

Any idea how I can do this please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function audioControl() {
    var playdiv = document.getElementById('playdiv');
    var pausediv = document.getElementById('pausediv');
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    if (myAudio.paused) {
      myAudio.play();
      pausediv.style.display = 'block';
      playdiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      myAudio.pause();
      pausediv.style.display = 'none';
      playdiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>

<audio id="myAudio" autoplay preload="metadata">
   <source src="http://IP:PORT/stream"></source>
   Unfortunately your browser doesn't support html5 audio streaming, please update your browser.
</audio>

<button id="control" class="control" onclick="audioControl()">
   <div id="playdiv" style="display:none">
      <img src="play.png" width="96" height="96" alt="Play"/>
   </div>
   <div id="pausediv" style="display:block">
      <img src="pause.png" width="96" height="96" alt="Pause"/>
   </div>
</button>
```

Comment: replace this: "display:none" <-> "display:block"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `autoplay` attribute on your `audio` element and then you should switch your `div`s style:

- `playdiv` should be with `style="display:block"`
- `pausediv` should be with `style="display:none"`

```js
function audioControl() {
    var playdiv = document.getElementById('playdiv');
    var pausediv = document.getElementById('pausediv');
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    if (myAudio.paused) {
        myAudio.play();
        pausediv.style.display = 'block';
        playdiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        myAudio.pause();
        pausediv.style.display = 'none';
        playdiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" preload="metadata">
   <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"/>
   Unfortunately your browser doesn't support html5 audio streaming, please update your browser.
</audio>

<button id="control" class="control" onclick="audioControl()">
   <div id="playdiv" style="display:block">
      <img src="play.png" width="96" height="96" alt="Play"/>
   </div>
   <div id="pausediv" style="display:none">
      <img src="pause.png" width="96" height="96" alt="Pause"/>
   </div>
</button>
```

Also available on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0trkfvo/3/).